# how to update text added in dimple.js stacked bar chart on data updation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js, stacked-chart

I have added text on my bar char as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558045/dimple-js-add-data-labels-to-each-bar-of-the-bar-chart) 
 but the problem in  when my data gets updated it overwrite my text everytime, previous text remains as it is there.

I would like to know how can I remove text everytime new data has arrived.

[image]

see the darkness of text, it is getting overwritten everytime new data is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the drawing logic to the `series.afterDraw` method as shown here: http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_labels

Then simply class the new labels:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("class", dimple._createClass(data.yField))
   .attr("x", ...
```

And remove them at the start of the afterDraw method:

```
svg.selectAll("text." + dimple._createClass(data.yField)).remove();
```

Comment: tried doing the same but it actually remove all text leaving only one behind. As in above case I have 7 bars so I need 7 text every time but when I do selectAll remove it remove newly added 6 as well, that is what the problematic for me.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, just include the y value (and series value if the bars are stacked) in the class name.  dimple has a method called `dimple._createClass()` which you can use, I'll amend my answer.